# How do you code a hamburger menu to make your navbar appear?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am trying to make a responsive nav bar menu by adding a hamburger menu so mobile users could also use my website. I coded the navbar and the hamburger menu. But my problem is that I don't know how to make my navbar appear when you click the hamburger menu icon. Can any of you guys tell me what the code for making my navbar appear onclick. My code is below. Resize your browser to a smaller width to see the hamburger menu if you can't see it. Please ask me questions if you did not understand my question. Again my code is below.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amatic+SC&display=swap");

* {
  font-family: "Amatic SC", cursive;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  background: #000;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
}

label.logo {
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
  line-height: 80px;
  padding: 0 100px;
}

nav ul {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 80px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 17px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 1px 13px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

a.active,
a:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    109.6deg,
    rgba(61, 245, 167, 1) 11.2%,
    rgba(9, 111, 224, 1) 91.1%
  );
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.nav-icon-5 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 15px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.nav-icon-5 span {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transition: 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.8, 0.5, 0.2, 1.4);
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  transition-duration: 500ms;
}
.nav-icon-5 span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 2px;
  left: 0px;
}
.nav-icon-5 span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 8px;
  left: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
}
.nav-icon-5 span:nth-child(3) {
  bottom: -1px;
  left: 0px;
}
.nav-icon-5:not(.open):hover span:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(-3deg) scaleY(-0.5);
}
.nav-icon-5:not(.open):hover span:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(3deg) scaleY(1.1);
}
.nav-icon-5:not(.open):hover span:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(-4deg) scaleY(1.1);
}
.nav-icon-5.open span:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 6px;
}
.nav-icon-5.open span:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}
.nav-icon-5.open span:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  bottom: 7px;
}

@media (max-width: 715px) {
  .nav {
    visibility: hidden;
  }

  .nav-icon-5 {
    bottom: 80px;
  }

  .nav-icon-5 span {
    visibility: visible;
    background-color: #fff;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 440px) {
  .nav-icon-5 span {
    visibility: visible !important;
    background-color: #fff;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>.WWW Home</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      media="screen"
      href="Global/navbar.css"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <label class="logo">.WWW</label>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#" class="active">The Domain</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">The News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Interesting Factoids</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sign Off</a></li>
        <li>
          <div class="icon nav-icon-5" onclick="Nav()">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </body>
  <script></script>
  <script href="main.js">
    const icons = document.querySelectorAll(".icon");
    icons.forEach((icon) => {
      icon.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        icon.classList.toggle("open");
      });
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: see the error? `ReferenceError: Nav is not defined`

Comment: @Bravo  I actually don't know how to fix that so how do I fix it

Comment: if onclick calls a function, make sure the function actually exists

Comment: Hey @Bravo, I am sorry I have another question. It is just that I making my first website. Sorry to disturb you but I add this function                                        
   const icons = document.querySelectorAll(".icon");
    icons.forEach((icon) => {
      icon.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        icon.classList.toggle("open");
      });
    });                                                                                                                                        But it is not working. What did I do wrong?

Comment: I find that when *"it is not working"* the best thing to do is to check the developer console for errors

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete unnecessary function `Nav` on the `.icon`

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amatic+SC&display=swap");

* {
  font-family: "Amatic SC", cursive;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  background: #000;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
}

label.logo {
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
  line-height: 80px;
  padding: 0 100px;
}

nav ul {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 80px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 17px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 1px 13px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

a.active,
a:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    109.6deg,
    rgba(61, 245, 167, 1) 11.2%,
    rgba(9, 111, 224, 1) 91.1%
  );
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.nav-icon-5 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 15px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.nav-icon-5 span {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transition: 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.8, 0.5, 0.2, 1.4);
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  transition-duration: 500ms;
}
.nav-icon-5 span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 2px;
  left: 0px;
}
.nav-icon-5 span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 8px;
  left: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
}
.nav-icon-5 span:nth-child(3) {
  bottom: -1px;
  left: 0px;
}
.nav-icon-5:not(.open):hover span:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(-3deg) scaleY(-0.5);
}
.nav-icon-5:not(.open):hover span:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(3deg) scaleY(1.1);
}
.nav-icon-5:not(.open):hover span:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(-4deg) scaleY(1.1);
}
.nav-icon-5.open span:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 6px;
}
.nav-icon-5.open span:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}
.nav-icon-5.open span:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  bottom: 7px;
}

@media (max-width: 715px) {
  .nav {
    visibility: hidden;
  }

  .nav-icon-5 {
    bottom: 80px;
  }

  .nav-icon-5 span {
    visibility: visible;
    background-color: #fff;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 440px) {
  .nav-icon-5 span {
    visibility: visible !important;
    background-color: #fff;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>.WWW Home</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      media="screen"
      href="Global/navbar.css"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <label class="logo">.WWW</label>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#" class="active">The Domain</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">The News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Interesting Factoids</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sign Off</a></li>
        <li>
          <div class="icon nav-icon-5">
            <span>Menu1</span>
            <span>Menu2</span>
            <span>Menu3</span>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </body>
  <script></script>
  <script href="main.js">
    const icons = document.querySelectorAll(".icon");
    icons.forEach((icon) => {
      icon.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        icon.classList.toggle("open");
      });
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I removed the Nav() , but how will navbar become visible on click and not visible when you click it again. As you can see in my CSS, when it reaches the media width, the .nav class visibility goes away and the hamburger menu icon shows up. My problem is that I don't how to code the javascript for when you click the icon, the .nav class will have the property visibility: visible;. When you click the hamburger menu icon again, the .nav class will have the property visibility: hidden;. Can you please tell me how to make that happen? Again please and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

from your code, I notice you are using floats, but here is a better convention and solution to your code:

in *HTML*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>.WWW Home</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      media="screen"
      href="Global/navbar.css"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <label class="logo">.WWW</label>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#" class="active">The Domain</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">The News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Interesting Factoids</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sign Off</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="icon nav-icon-5" ">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </body>
  <script></script>
  <script href="main.js">
    const icons = document.querySelectorAll(".icon");
    const nav = document.querySelector(".nav")
    icons.forEach((icon) => {
      icon.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        icon.classList.toggle("open");
        nav.classList.toggle("menu-open")
      });
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

*in CSS*

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amatic+SC&display=swap");

* {
  font-family: "Amatic SC", cursive;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  background: #000;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 100px;
}

label.logo {
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
  line-height: 80px;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
}


nav ul li a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 17px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 1px 13px;
}

a.active,
a:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    109.6deg,
    rgba(61, 245, 167, 1) 11.2%,
    rgba(9, 111, 224, 1) 91.1%
  );
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.nav-icon-5 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 15px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}
.nav-icon-5 span {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transition: 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.8, 0.5, 0.2, 1.4);
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  transition-duration: 500ms;
}
.nav-icon-5 span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 2px;
  left: 0px;
}
.nav-icon-5 span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 8px;
  left: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
}
.nav-icon-5 span:nth-child(3) {
  bottom: -1px;
  left: 0px;
}
.nav-icon-5:not(.open):hover span:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(-3deg) scaleY(-0.5);
}
.nav-icon-5:not(.open):hover span:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(3deg) scaleY(1.1);
}
.nav-icon-5:not(.open):hover span:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(-4deg) scaleY(1.1);
}
.nav-icon-5.open span:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 6px;
}
.nav-icon-5.open span:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}
.nav-icon-5.open span:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  bottom: 7px;
}

@media (max-width: 715px) {
  nav {
    position: relative;
  }
  .nav {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0%;
  }

  .nav-icon-5 {
    display: block;
  }

  nav ul {
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
  }

  nav ul li {
    margin: 10px 0;
  }

  .menu-open {
    display: block;
    transform: translateY(108px);
    background-color: red;
  }

  .nav-icon-5 span {
    visibility: visible;
    background-color: #fff;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 440px) {
  .nav-icon-5 span {
    visibility: visible !important;
    background-color: #fff;
  }
}
```

Comment: OMG IT WORKS!! Thank you so much. I appreciate you!